# Is hdpi and mdpi still used in android kitkat and up

Tags: screen, screen-resolution

Have a general question if this is something that could be ruled out or it all depends.

I am developing an app for Android KitKat and above. But i have never seen a phone that have hdpi and are able to upgrade the OS to KitKat.

Is there a way to see how many phones still uses hdpi and mdpi? 
Because it will be a big problem for me if i need to support every screen.

Comment: Be careful, you're mixing Android version with screen density: [Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_4_10_1-6247.php) is mdpi and supports up to KitKat 4.4.2 officially. You also have to think about custom ROM above KitKat, like CyanogenMod which supports up to Marshmallow. (Further list of screen density list: https://design.google.com/devices/)

Comment: yeah that was what i was wondering. If there is a device with that density and OS version. Because then i will have to tell our designer to make some changes to some views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always keep [this page](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) bookmarked for things like this.

You can make some educated guesses using this data.

As of Feb 1 2016, the percentage of devices on an OS version pre-KitKat (if I did the math correctly) is 29.2%.

Since 42.4% of all devices have hdpi screen density...

**At least 13.2% of all devices out there are hdpi with KitKat or later.**

It's likely that it's more, since you can count on most of the ldpi/mdpi devices being in the pre-KitKat group.

If all 16.2% of ldpi/mdpi devices are in the pre-KitKat group (which most likely are), then the total hdpi KitKat-and-later group grows to 29.5%